# Wireless USB mouse dongle causes in built speaker not to work?

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, speakers

I have this HP Elitebook G4 laptop with **Conexant ISST Audio** speaker. I also have a wireless mouse that has a USB dongle that goes into the  a USB port on the right side of the laptop. The mouse and the speaker work fine but when I restart my laptop, the speaker does not work. I checked the **Windows Audio** and **Windows Audio Endpoint Builder** services to make sure they are running, they are both running. The funny thing is that when I unplug the wireless USB dongle and restart the laptop, the speaker works fine. It is a behavior thats manifested today in the morning, the Audio Driver is **Bang and Olufsen**, could this be caused by driver conflict as a result of a recent change of hardware and how can I resolve it.

After unplugging and restarting, the speaker works fine but when I plug the dongle again and restart then the speaker does not work.

Is it a possibility for the Audio Driver and the USB dongle driver to have some similar information that confuses the system so the system thinks they are one device so the other device becomes unusable?